# Flask/Werkzeug equivalence of web.py app.request()

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I'm porting an app from web.py to Flask, mainly because web.py support for Python 3 is spotty and there seems to be less and less interest in web.py.

But what I can't find in Flask/Werkzeug is a way to use the router to do dispatching of internal requests within my application. The app is structured such that there will be a lot of intra-application calls, and in web.py I handle these more or less as follows:

```
app = web.application(....)

def callUrl(url, method, env, data):
    parserUrl = url lib.parse.urlparse(url)
    if parsedUrl.scheme == '' and parsedUrl.netloc == '':
        # local call
        res = app.request(url, method=method, data=data, env=env)
        ...
    else:
        assert env == {}
        res = requests.request(url, method=method, data=data)
        ....
```

I am trying to find a way to do something similar with Flask, but apparently I am looking in the wrong places. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Why would your application ever call itself in this way? If you want to call a function in your program, why not just call that function instead of using some kind of HTTP request? Apart from testing, I don't see a use case for this at all.

Comment: I agree with @rje: making calls via internal requests is an antipattern in Flask. You should structure your code with classes and functions and call them directly.

Comment: The app in question is an IoT controller with a database full of rules (if such-and-such a condition is true trigger this-and-that REST call). Most of the rules are internal, i.e. their URLs point to other points in the database. Some are external (for example to turn on appliances). So the general case is "make a call to a URL", but by far the most common case is that that call is going to be internal.

Comment: @Jack Jansen thanks for the explanation. My strategy would be that the rules could hold either a URL or a function name. That way you never have to do an internal API call, because that's just weird ;)

Comment: @rje nice suggestion but it wouldn't fly. The rules themselves are database entries, and actually entered into the database by the end user (through a front-end). But unless someone else comes with a brilliant solution I'll do sort-of what you suggest, by manually looking through the werkzeug `Map`s and matching the urls and then calling the view function myself...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answering my own question. The solution I chose was to basically re-implement `app.request` from web.py by filling an environ dictionary with all the required WSGI variables (`REQUEST_METHOD`, `PATH_INFO`, etc), including `wsgi.input` as an `io.BytesIO()` object that feeds the correct data into the WSGI app.

Then I created a suitable start_response() method to save the headers, and called

`resultData = app.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)`

The flask app goes through all the motions of pushing requests and environments and does all the routing, and I get the returned data back in `resultData` (and the headers with any errors and such have been passed to my `start_response` method).